# -1006F error message when trying to recover mac

Tags: macbook-pro, recovery, install, reboot

my macbook pro crashed and i sent it for repairs.. so the guy installed a new hard drive but then sent it back with a screen having a flashing folder with a question mark.. so i looked at [this](http://support.apple.com/kb/ts1440) page and basically restarted by pressing the `option` button. So I came to a screen that asked for my internet password.. then i clicked on a button that says internet recovery.. then i got this screen:

[image]

after a while I got a screen with error: `apple.com/support -1006F`.. any idea what that means or what I should do next?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at this discussion on [Apple Support Communities about -1006f](https://discussions.apple.com/message/22274019#22274019) which contains this solution :

> Hold Command and R keys while the Mac is starting to start in Recovery HD. If you can start up, open Disk Utility, select Macintosh HD in the sidebar and verify the disk. If it gives you an error, repair your drive. If it can't be repaired, you need a new hard disk.
>
> If you can't start, hold Command, Option (Alt) and R keys

Comment: yeah i'd say i need a new harddrive.. b/c i triple checked that my internet connection is stable.. and connected by ethernet rather than wifi.. and this message comes *right away*.. so there is no chance it's about a bad connection..rather it's about a broken hard drive..

Comment: For people landing here after they deleted their partition and now getting the 1006F error, hold Command + Option + P + R key to reset saved config and then reboot with Command + Option + R to get into internet recovery without any errors.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the good news:

You got in to the Internet recovery mode.
So you Mac is alive but not well.

Normally the next step for the recovery would be to establish the Internet connection.

If it works you would see a spinning Globe with progress bar.

Since you do not have that here is the bad news.

You might have a broken Internet, so make sure the computer is connected to a live Internet.

Needless to say, you would not need all the above if you had a external recovery disk.

Anyway, try again this time going straight in to the Internet recovery.

Too use Lion Internet Recovery, instead of the Recovery Partition.

You must have an internet connection, and have handy any router credentials for connecting to the Internet. ([See the section on supported protocols](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4718))

When starting the computer, press Command+Option+R until you see a spinning globe appear along with a message about the recovery mode.

This will force your Mac to launch Internet Recovery. You'll know that you are in Internet Recovery when you see a spinning globe and a meter running underneath it.

Comment: I was getting a similar '-1 006U'. This is the right answer for me, as it turns out it was caused by my WiFi AP requiring a webpage login. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to add another answer to help anyone who may encounter this. My scenario was for during the Yosemite recovery, error was showing the internet globe icon and "apple.com/support -2105F" so slightly different error number.

Prior to this, the recovery process was stuck for hours on "Chunk download failed, retrying...". Eventually I aborted that process, and that is when I restarted and was stuck with this internet globe icon.

To resolve this, I accidentally happened upon holding the **OPTION** key down (which was suggested at the first post) during power on. By doing so, the Wifi Network prompt appeared to allow me to choose ANOTHER network (non router one, but the DSL one I have on my modem). This was successful, and allowed the recovery process to complete in just over one hour.

So in my case, it did appear to be a Wifi/network/firewall issue. Although I did check and made sure I was using WPA2 and AES, still it did not work.

Hope this helps someone who is tearing their hair out :)

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem "-1007f*". Rebooting with <kbd>option</kbd> key pressed and typing in my WiFi password fixed it.

Answer (score -1):

Remove battery for 5 mints reconncet that should do it

Comment: This should be a last resort, and would be no different then an SMC reset for this particular issue.