# Internet Recovery failed -1006f

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, internet, recovery

My problem is same as with this question
[-1006F error message when trying to recover mac](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/124870/1006f-error-message-when-trying-to-recover-mac)

I have follow that question which direct me to this thread

https://discussions.apple.com/message/22273842#22273842

from this link it says I need to buy new harddisk, so I bought a new one and installed it.

Now when I boot up the macbook it automatically goes in to internet recovery, but again in middle of loading I still get the -1006f error again?

Comment: There is a step missing. Did you format your new disk? Did your reset your PRAM ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's solved already.

The problem is my internet connection not stable at that moment.
when I had a stable connection it worked flawlessy!